# JSON Stringify & AJAX parse errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have been at this for hours trying everything I could possibly find suggested on the web, however it continues to fail. When I encode function parameters with JSON.stringify and then pass it to my PHP handler via AJAX, I am getting an Alert pop-up saying parsererror.

It is apparently an issue within the Javascript but I cannot determine where at this point.

Can anyone perhaps spot what I am doing wrong here?

```
            // JSON Encode to pass via AJAX to PHP
            var params = { "id": player };
            var params2 = JSON.stringify(params);

            // {"id":"939952da-23df-4ff1-b66c-61018b621645"}
            console.log(params2);

            cellOptions.innerHTML = "<button onclick='sendAction(\"kickPlayer\"," + params2 + ")'>Kick</button>";
```

AJAX

```
function sendAction(cmd, params)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handler.php",
        data: { 'action': cmd, 'params': params },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data['status'] == 'failed')
            {

            }
            else if (data['status'] == 'success')
            {

            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); alert("Message: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Put `console.log(params)` in the beginning of `sendAction`. What does it print?

Comment: Object {id: "939952da-23df-4ff1-b66c-61018b621645"}

Comment: @Rory I already tried this prior without using stringify. I was just passing the object directly and also did not work, where I encountered a discussion saying to use JSON instead

Comment: The problem is with the server response, request looks fine. What do you get from backend?

Comment: What is the exact text in the alert box ? That is very important in understanding the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By coding this :

```
dataType: 'json',
```

you tell jQuery to expect a JSON String in the response (from the backend, i.e. our PHP code). So on the callback, jQuery parses the string, and since you are not receiving a valid JSON string from the backend, it fails to parse it, and throws this parser error.

Edit: see jQuery documentation:

> ```
>  dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
> ```
>
> Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I've been eyeing that thinking it may have something to do with that but too inexperienced to be sure. Should I remove it or change it to something else?

Comment: Well.. this can be one of the resons... but since server code is hidden... and alert text is not clearly known... it can also be a parse-error on server side.

Comment: You should return a valid JSON from your PHP code ;-) If you have an object you want to return, just use `json_encode()` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so fixated thinking it was a JS issue that I didn't even notice my problems in the PHP code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not stringify the params before you pass them to your sendAction function.

Instead Stringify the entire object you send to the server. e.g.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'action': cmd, 'params': params }),
```